# Sharing video to Instagram Story

Tags: ios, swift, video, instagram

I have an app which allows users to add audio to their videos. I would like to give the user a chance to share the video they've worked on directly to their Instagram story, if Instagram is installed. What I've noticed is that Instagram doesn't appear in the social list of UIActivityViewController which is strange.

Any advice or pointers will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you wrote UIActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes, comment that line & try again